# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat (python 3.6)

Tags: python, import, sympy

I am trying to import this :

```
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import ufuncify
```

yet, when I try to actually use ufuncify (I don't get an error when I just import it)... I get the error:

```
sympy.utilities.autowrap.CodeWrapError: Error while executing command: C:\python36\pythonw.exe setup.py build_ext --inplace. Command output is:
running build_ext

running build_src

build_src

building extension "wrapper_module_0" sources

build_src: building npy-pkg config files

No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils

customize MSVCCompiler

customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext

building 'wrapper_module_0' extension

compiling C sources

error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I have tried to install Visual Studio 2017, yet I still have the same error despite uninstalling and reinstalling sympy.

Comment: I would suggest using Anaconda. It generally handles these compiler issues better. It also already comes with Sympy.

Comment: I had the same problem when I ran my code in Juypter though